# Is there an easy way to include images from https://imgur.com?

Tags: support, editing, image

Sometimes, posters provide links to https://imgur.com rather than to https://i.stack.imgur.com.

Then, if I want to include the image in the poster's question, I first have to open the https://imgur.com image, download it, and then upload it the correct way.

It's not a big deal, but is there an easier way? I suspect not but I want to be sure!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of downloading and re-uploading you can just copy the *image* URL and paste it in the image upload tool:

[image]
(click '*paste*')

[image]

Comment: I'm glad I asked!

Comment: @DKBose This works with any URL of (not very large) images, not just imgur ones.

Comment: That makes sense otherwise it would circumvent the size restriction.

Answer (score 7):

It's actually a little bit easier than pomsky points out.

You don't need the URL or to open the image box. You can just:

1. Right click the image, click "Copy Image"
2. Then paste that image straight into an edit box.

It'll upload it to the right part of Imgur and insert the link.

[image]

Comment: An [animated] image showing how to upload an image of two images showing how to upload an image. That was quite confusing at first :p

Comment: Well this *is* Meta 